# Can you change a tabbedpage's child navigation stack from app.xaml.cs?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set up automatic logging in when a user reopens my app so that it will check for existing login credentials saved in app.current.properties and when finding some, navigate the user to the proper tabbedpage, and change the current page from the default login screen to the account main page.

I've tried something that through research seemed like it should work, specifically accessing the child page in question (login) and pushing a new page onto it via its navigation element. This hasn't worked, and neither have some other much more janky solutions I've tried implementing.

In App.xaml.cs

```cs
protected override void OnStart()
        {
            AuthService.LoadUserCredentials();

            if (AuthService.authenticated)
            {
                var page = new MainTabs();
                page.CurrentPage = page.Children[2];

                ContactService.RefreshData();
                var page2 = new PinCodePage(false);
                page.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page2).ConfigureAwait(false);

                MainPage = page;
            }
        }
```

Should note that my app is setup in a way that the mainpage of the whole application is a tabbedpage, which has 3 pages, the third one being the Login page. When a user normally logs in successfully, that page has a new page added over it, Account, and the Login page is popped out, effectively removing it.

The expected result is that when a user opens the app after closing it/shutting it down after having been logged in, it checks for user stored info, and finding it, replaces the Login page with the Account page. If it finds nothing, it ignores the replacement of the login page and leaves it there.

Comment: what does "hasn't worked" mean?  Is it crashing?  Giving an error?  Just not doing what you want?  if it's the last one, what specifically is it doing (or not doing)?

Comment: It's not showing any change at all, when the app starts and I know it has user data saved that it can access, it just starts at the first page of the tabbedpage, and when I navigate to the third page, its at the default login page.

Comment: Have you stepped through OnStart to verify it’s really doing what you think it is?

Comment: I think the users data may be removed when the app is closed, because I know it exists after the user logs in, but it isn't detected by the check I debug through the OnStart function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this (here is a sample simple,you could use your page and data replace):

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
       if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("isLogin"))
        {
            bool isLogin = (bool)App.Current.Properties["isLogin"];
            if (isLogin)
            {
                TabbedPage p = MainPage as TabbedPage;
                var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new AccoutPage());
                navigationPage.IconImageSource = "tab_accout.png";
                navigationPage.Title = "Accout";
                p.Children.Add(navigationPage);
                p.Children.RemoveAt(2);
                p.CurrentPage = navigationPage;
            }
        }
    }
```

**update**:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        App.Current.Properties["isLogin"] = true;
        App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
        TabbedPage p = App.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage;
        var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new AccoutPage());
        navigationPage.IconImageSource = "tab_accout.png";
        navigationPage.Title = "Accout";
        p.Children.Add(navigationPage);
        p.Children.RemoveAt(2);
        p.CurrentPage = navigationPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the check for if they're logged in never passes. I have in the login function it writing a key 'isLoggedIn' with value 'true' to the app properties, but this check in OnStart never passes, actually because it seems the properties doesn't contain the key at all. This testing is done *after* I've already logged in once, so the data should be saved to the device.

Comment: @cjpartin i update the answer,show the LoginPage,i store the state use `App.Current.Properties["isLogin"] = true;`,then i close the application and restart it,it still get the correct state in OnStart method

Comment: I tried how you have it there, except that my submit button action is inside a viewmodel, and also did a check to make sure the setting is saved to properties immediately after logging in with a popup window stating its status, but when I close the app and relaunch it the setting does not exist at all. The check for contains key comes up false on relaunch and only exists if I never close the application.

Comment: @cjpartin first,the Properties dictionary can only serialize primitive types for storage,second you could try to call `await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();` after you save the properties

Comment: I'm only serializing strings and bools, nothing else. And I've tried both with await and without, both ways it saves correctly, but it doesn't persist past closing the app. I know it is saving because I check with debug to console line telling me the status of the key, and it exists after login. On app close, something happens that makes the properties dictionary erased because all values within are null afterwards in OnStart().

Comment: @cjpartin after use `await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync()` still lose the value ? if yes,may could try anoher way to save the value,try [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: I'm working with Xamarin.Essentials and its SecureStorage now and everything works great, not sure why App.Current.Properties isn't working for me. Thanks for the help though.